# How to get measurement result on Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, measurement

I want to get measurement result from my circuit output, like '00', '01', '10', or '11' because want to process it further classically. Any suggestion? We can see the highest probability '01'. How I can extract the result?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to know your job id fist. You can get it from https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/jobs:

[image: sreenshot]

With the job id and the backend, you can enter that information to retrieve the job in Qiskit:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
job = provider.get_backend(<backend_name>).retrieve_job(<job_id>)
```

With the job, you can access the count like this:

```
counts = job.result().get_counts()
print(counts)
```

```
{'000000': 8,
 '000001': 16,
 '010000': 2,
 '010001': 3,
 '010100': 6,
 '010101': 2,
 '010110': 3,
 ...
}
```

Comment: So i just take the highest value from the ```count``` result ?

Comment: You said you wanted "to get measurement result [...] to process it further classically". I don't know what's your classical process. If you want do `counts.most_frequent()` to get the result with the higher count.

Comment: Oww I think I get confused, so the output of the jobs are probability of all possible state ? I think I need the ```counts.most_frequent()``` for my code thanks